# jQuery .next() div showing all siblings instead of just one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm testing a pagination type where the buttons are on a separate div from the target.

When I try to toggle the next div of the body, all of them are toggling, instead of just one.

```js
$('#next_q').on('click', function(){
  $('.question-item').hide().next('.question-item').show();
})
```

```css
.question-item:not(:first-child){display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="question-item">Q1</div>
  <div class="question-item">Q2</div>
  <div class="question-item">Q3</div>
</div>
<div class="box-footer">
  <button>Prev</button>
  <button id="next_q">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can just make use of  :visible in your code :

 $('.question-item:visible').hide().next('.question-item').show();

Comment: On top of using `:visible', you should try to get the first element from the list returned by `next` like so: `$('.question-item:visible').hide().next('.question-item').first().show();`

Comment: @MihaiPantea No real need for using `.first()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `:visible` to select the `question-item` that is currently visible

```
$('#next_q').on('click', function(){
    $('.question-item:visible').hide().next('.question-item').show();
})
```

also if you want it not to "skip" past the last element, use

```
if ($('.question-item:visible').prev('.question-item').length)
```

```js
$('#next_q').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.question-item:visible').next('.question-item').length)
    $('.question-item:visible').hide().next('.question-item').show();
})

$('#prev_q').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.question-item:visible').prev('.question-item').length)
  $('.question-item:visible').hide().prev('.question-item').show();
})
```

```css
.question-item:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="question-item">Q1</div>
  <div class="question-item">Q2</div>
  <div class="question-item">Q3</div>
</div>
<div class="box-footer">
  <button id="prev_q">Prev</button>
  <button id="next_q">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me. And thanks for the bit about not skipping the last item :) Thanks!

Comment: @BryanAldrin You're very welcome, happy to help. If any of the answer helped you, please consider marking one of them as answer so other people with the same problem will know what helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the current visible `.question-item` and hide it and then show the next `.question-item`. I also added the `not last-child` selector since I thought that you might want to stop at the last question.

```js
    $('#next_q').on('click', function(){
     $('.question-item:visible:not(:last-child)').hide().next('.question-item').show();
    });
    
    $('#prev_q').on('click', function(){
     $('.question-item:visible:not(:first-child)').hide().prev('.question-item').show();
    });
```

```css
.question-item:not(:first-child){display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="question-item">Q1</div>
  <div class="question-item">Q2</div>
  <div class="question-item">Q3</div>
</div>
<div class="box-footer">
  <button id="prev_q">Prev</button>
  <button id="next_q">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.data()` to store an integer reflecting an index of the `.question-item` elements `.length`, use `++` and `%` operators to cycle the indexes passed to `.eq()` from current index or `0` through `.question-items` `.length`

```js
$('#next_q')
  .data({
    "index": 0,
    items: $(".question-item")
  })
  .on("click", function() {
    $(this).data().items
      .hide()
      .eq(++$(this).data().index % $(this).data().items.length)
      .show();
  })
```

```css
.question-item:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="question-item">Q1</div>
  <div class="question-item">Q2</div>
  <div class="question-item">Q3</div>
</div>
<div class="box-footer">
  <button>Prev</button>
  <button id="next_q">Next</button>
</div>
```